# Edit comments as if separate lines?

Tags: formatting, comments

Is there a way to edit comments so that they will all be aligned without having to align them manually with <kbd>tab</kbd>?

i.e., How can I get something like that?

```
some text          %comment
some more text     %another comment
&c.                %=etc.
```

without manually adjusting each comment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be interested by the [tabular plugin](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) it allows to align text based on patterns.

In your case if you have

```
some text  %comment
some more text %another comment
&c.  %=etc.
```

with your cursor on the first line you can use `3V` to select the lines you want to treat and then `:Tabular /%` and tabular will automatically indent the text like that:

```
some text          %comment
some more text     %another comment
&c.                %=etc.
```

The plugin is pretty powerful and can be used to do much more complex operations.

**Edit** As jjaderberg pointed it out in this case you don't need to select the text: Tabular is pretty clever and can "guess" how to format the text. For example you can use `:Tabularize` (without selection neither pattern) and the plugin will still align the comments.

Also an interesting mapping to add to your `.vimrc` is:

```
vnoremap T :Tabular /
```

This way you can visually select a part of text and use <kbd>T</kbd> to easily start tabular.

**Edit 2** I was looking around to find fun stuff to do with tabular and I just found out a [nice Tim Pope's gist](https://gist.github.com/tpope/287147) which could be interesting here:

```
inoremap <silent> %   %<Esc>:call <SID>align('%')<CR>a

function! s:align(aa)
  let p = '^.*\s'.a:aa.'\s.*$'
  if exists(':Tabularize') && (getline(line('.')-1) =~# p || getline(line('.')+1) =~# p)
    let column = strlen(substitute(getline('.')[0:col('.')],'[^'.a:aa.']','','g'))
    let position = strlen(matchstr(getline('.')[0:col('.')],'.*'.a:aa.':\s*\zs.*'))
    exec 'Tabularize/'.a:aa.'/l1'
    normal! 0
    call search(repeat('[^'.a:aa.']*'.a:aa,column).'\s\{-\}'.repeat('.',position),'ce',line('.'))
  endif
endfunction
```

It maps `%` so that when you write several consecutive lines containing a `%`, the comments will be automatically aligned on the fly. And when you write a single line with `%` it will only be added without more indent.

Note that a possible improvement would be to define the mapping according to the file time so that the correct comment character is mapped for each language.

Comment: +1 In this case you can probably omit the `3V` as Tabular usually guesses correctly which selection of text you want to operate on.

Comment: @jjaderberg You're right I edited my answer. Thanks :-)

Comment: You might also be interested in [vim-easy-align](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align). I like particularly the LiveEasyAlign command, which allows real time customization of the align command. This is useful for more advanced cases.